# MatLab compiler auxiliary variables

Tags: matlab, optimization

I was wondering, does the MatLab compiler automatically change several calls to a function on the same object to one call ?

i. e.

```
someVector=zeros(length(someOtherVector),1);

for i=1:length(someOtherVector)
  ... 
end
```

"Optimized"

```
aSize=length(someOtherVector);

someVector=zeros(aSize,1);
for i=1:aSize
  ... 
end
```

By-question: How is this optimization technique formally called ? I understand, for instance, the JVM does this kind of stuff.

Comment: About the second question: Maybe you referring to Just in Time (JIT) compilation?

Comment: I'm guessing this could be done (for simple MatLab functions) at compile time, but I might be wrong

Comment: For the second question: I am curious about the specific name for this optimization technique and if the JVM does this.

Comment: As i mentioned I believe you are talking about Matlab's JIT Compilation Engine, you can read about it [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/02/12/run-code-faster-with-the-new-matlab-execution-engine/) for example. I think that this is a step before the JVM, and something that Matlab specifically does, but I am not sure. Also it is hard to say what exact optimization it performs, but I would guess the example you used is certainly possible.

Comment: Thats what people do when they write compilers: write a huge load of symplification rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MATLAB JIT Compiler makes plenty of optimizations, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't do the optimization you're suggesting.

To see why, imagine that you'd written your own function called `length` which returned a random integer whatever its input, and put it on the path so that it shadowed the built-in `length`. Then your second version would not only not be an optimized version of the first, it would actually have different effects.

Indeed, if you *really* wanted to mess around, you could implement `length` so that it wrote a new file called `length` and put that ahead of itself on the path, so that it would have entirely different effects the next time around.

MATLAB is quite a flexible language, which has a lot of advantages, but that makes it less possible to perform the sort of static analysis on MATLAB code that these sort of JIT optimizations would require. Java is much easier to statically analyse, so the JVM can perform more optimizations.